# Make the miniature squares under a barGraph scrollable using mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a barGraph similar to the one below.

I was wondering if the miniature ( maybe the word is not accurate, I'm talking about the little coloured squares under the x axis, on the left of the word "Company" on the picture ) can be set to scrollable when the graph contains a lot of datas.

If so, is there as well a way to set those squares touchable and on touch, to center the view on the corresponding element of a barGraph?

I add that the graph itself is and has to be scrollable.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little squares you are talking about represent the `Legend` which shows the different datasets used.

It is not possible to make this scrollable by default.

What you could do is create your own miniature `BarChart` below your actual barchart and use that one.